# memory consumption alert

Tags: memory, performance, monitoring, vps

My VPS has reported a memory consumption alert says reached 273% and I cannot access any of my sites.

But I checked on the terminal today and it does not look like a memory problem. Am I correct in thinking memory is fine?

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          1004        110        893          0         56         20
-/+ buffers/cache:         33        970
Swap:         2047          1       2046
```

The VPS reports my using 2.73 GB of allotted 1024 so they are wanting me to move up a plan but clearly I'm not using anywhere near that amount. But it appears over the weekend something spiked the usage but none of my sites were active so what could it be? How can I test the problem?

#### screenshot of graph

[image: my usage report]

What are you supposed to do to get the sites all up again? I'm at a loss.

update: I have looked in /var/log/messages and found this : `rsyslogd was HUPed`
 but now I've found mysql has disappeared!

Comment: Did you check *at the time* that the problem was reported? If it was transient and you check later, everything will appear nominal.

Comment: No but I see there was a spike over the weekend but as my sites are inactive, can't imagine what it could be. The only thing is they had maintenance of their whole set up which is coincidental.

Comment: Anyway when I go to any of my sites says cannot connect to the server so I am waiting to hear back from the provider but they are notoriously difficult esp as I have "unmanaged'account.